# Arxiv substantial text overlap after breaking up paper

Tags: arxiv

I recently broke up an overly long paper A into two smaller, self-contained papers B and C, which I intend to submit separately. On arxiv, B was uploaded as a revised version of A, whereas C was created as a new submission.

C has been flagged has having substantial text overlap with A/B. My question is: could this refer to the older version A or does it necessarily refer to the current version B? In other words, does arxiv take into account older versions of articles when scanning for similarities?

Answer (score 11):

While arXiv does not publish the exact details of their implementation, in [their help section on overlap detection](https://arxiv.org/help/overlap), they have to following notes that may be useful for you:

> Submitters can preempt the addition of a text overlap admin note by marking any known overlaps in advance in the "Comments" header (as long as the earlier appearance of the text has a coauthor in common): for example, "this article draws heavily from arXiv:x, arXiv:y," or "this article supersedes arXiv:z."

and

> A submitter who believes that an admin note indicating text overlap has been incorrectly applied to their article should contact arXiv moderation with a detailed explanation or justification.

In short: if you have sections that are intended to be in common between B and C, point them out in the comments, then flag for attention from a moderator.